# Why was my answer on the Israel/Palestine question deleted?

Tags: discussion, support

Could someone please explain why [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/12462/3835) was deleted? Is it merely because my answer was critical of Israel -- a country that myself and others demonstrated kills children?

So one mod deleted it without consulting the other two? What would it look like if the mod was editorializing himself? In my eyes I submitted to the rules of the site, and even permitted others to remove opinionated statements. My question is well sourced and speaks right to the question, *"Do Israeli soldiers kill Palestinian kids?"*

I'm mildly offended that a site that markets itself as *skeptical* has one corrupt mod pandering to the flags of others who are emotionally attached to a religious and nationalistic state.

Comment: I'm mildly offended that you would accuse a mod of being *corrupt* based on practically zero evidence, before he has a chance to defend himself. Perhaps he has a good reason you can't see. Perhaps he made a mistake. Perhaps there is a third option.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - I've removed your argumentative comments, and I've asked the mod in question to take a look here. Please abstain from pointless and fantasy based accusations from this point on. To all **please only on topic comments and take _any_ discussion or reply to the [chat]**

Comment: @Jamiec Careful with unproven accusations of antisemitism. Let’s not mix criticism of a country’s politics with discrimination against a religion or culture, especially when so historically loaded.

Comment: @Jamiec Let me rephrase this slightly: I will *not* stand unproven accusations of such sort here. It poisons the well in an already difficult discussion.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - on that point there can be no argument. I'll delete my earlier comments.

Answer (score 9):

Evan, first of all, I am atheist, so I find it difficult to comprehend how I could be viewed as Zionist, or having any respect for any particular religion...  I think they are ALL stupid, childish, and frankly a detriment to mankind (but that is neither here nor there).

The answer had received several flags for displaying a graphic image that was in poor taste, and when it had been edited out, you had rolled it back to display the same image.  Initially I deleted it while at the same time Fabian had been performing an edit.  I did delete it because of the numerous flags I received on it because of the image, not because of the content of the answer, and because you were rolling it back despite the community showing that the image was unacceptable for this community.

It had *nothing* to do with being critical of Israel or any other country.  In the future, if you want to include images in your answers, attempt to keep them tasteful, or at least within the bounds of community standards.  I generally tend to be quite laize faire with postings on the site, but when I receive multiple flags, I do act on them.

I can re-open the answer if you consider the inputs of the community and leave the questionable picture out.

Comment: I never rolled it back to preserve an image.

Answer (score 5):

I've restored the answer. Please avoid graphic images in the future, even as links.